# LWC - Updating Record with Imported Schema

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm wondering if I am doing this correctly.  I'm trying to use the static schema for referential integrity as recommended here, under [Import References to Salesforce Objects and Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about), but it doesn't seem "right" to me:

```
import ISFLAGGED_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/AccountHistory__c.IsFlagged__c';

...

handleReset (event) {
    let resetFields = {         
        [ISFLAGGED_FIELD.fieldApiName]: { value: false }
    }
    let recordToReset = generateRecordInputForUpdate({
        //id: this.recordId,
        id: 'a2I4F000000ai15UAA',
        fields:  resetFields           
    });

    updateRecord(recordToReset);    
}
```

I've seen it done this way as well,  but it seems to defeat the purpose of importing the schema

```
let resetFields = { IsFlagged__c: { value: false} }
```

Any help and tips are appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you showed where generateRecordInputForUpdate and updateRecord come from. Also, Please explain the motivation for your question in more detail. Just edit the question to add these details rather than commenting please.

Comment: @PhilW These functions are included in the LWC UI Record API:  [generateRecordInputForUpdate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_generate_record_input_update) and [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record)

Comment: thanks for the clarification. You might have had your own same-named functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the example here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record

The argument that is passed into the `record` parameter when calling `updateRecord(record)` is in this structure:

```
{
    fields: {
        Id: 'a2I4F000000ai15UAA',
        [ISFLAGGED_FIELD.fieldApiName]: false
    }
}
```

Try it without `generateRecordInputForUpdate()` and the "value" property like in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, let me give that object a try.  I appreciate the tip.

Comment: For me, this worked without the [ and ]